# chrome extension inject news ticker at the top of the page without overlapping page header

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I want to inject news ticker as part of the page (not fixed position) at the top so that if user scrolls the page ticker will move with page. When I insert ticker as the first child of body, it is not appearning in the start. See screenshot below. It is overlapping the search bar in this youtube homepage case

[image]

Comment: There's no universal solution. You will have to adjust each site's CSS individually.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a custom CSS class name to add a top margin on the current web page. An example is the Finance Toolbar Chrome extension, which places the bar on top of the web page. That by inserting a top marge on the body element to keep the stock bar visible on the top.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/finance-toolbar-real-time/cichbngoomgnobmmjpagmbkimbamigie

It is Free and Open-Source browser extension:
https://github.com/stefanvd/Browser-Extensions/tree/master/Finance-Toolbar/Finance-Toolbar-Chrome-extension